# Setting text of element with JS ignores \n linebreak?

Tags: javascript, html, string, line-breaks

I want to set a the text of a paragraph element via JS. The string contains **line breaks** (\n), but they are **not visible in the paragraph**.

This is the **desired result**:

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<br> 
  consetetur sadipscing elitr,<br> 
  sed diam nonumy <br> eirmod tempor...
</p>
```

This it how it looks when I **set the text via JS**:

```js
document.getElementById("text").textContent = 
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,\n" + 
"consetetur sadipscing elitr,\n" + 
"sed diam nonumy \n eirmod tempor...";
```

```html
<p id="text"></p>
```

How can I **achieve the behaviour of the first example with JS?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the MDN documentation for [`HTMLElement.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText):

> Note: `innerText` is easily confused with [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent), but there are important differences between the two. Basically, `innerText` is aware of the rendered appearance of text, while `textContent` is not.

So, if you use `innerText` instead, you'll get the expected result:

```js
document.getElementById("text").innerText = 
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,\n" + 
"consetetur sadipscing elitr,\n" + 
"sed diam nonumy \n eirmod tempor...";
```

```html
<p id="text"></p>
```

Don't reach for `innerText` all the time: `textContent` is more performant... but in some cases like this, `innerText` is the right tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this too. Using insertAdjacentHTML

```js
let innerElem = 
` Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<br> 
  consetetur sadipscing elitr,<br> 
  sed diam nonumy <br> eirmod tempor...`;
      
document.getElementById("text").insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin",innerElem);
```

```html
<p id="text"></p>
```